# Selenium +python перевести страницу

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium

как перевести страницу на русский язык в selenium используя веб драйвер chrome?
например вот [эту](https://www.fragrancex.com/products/_cid_cologne-am-lid_a-am-pid_79963m__products.html?sid=abeawi&src=googleShopping&productmode=us&currency=usd&coupon=fx15)

Comment: Открыть через гугл-переводчик или его аналог?

Comment: так долго будет (

Comment: @gil9red просто иногда он переводит сам страницу и хотелось как то это настроить если это возможно(

Comment: Переводит, скорее всего, плагин. Убедитесь, что при запуск браузера через селениум там доступен тот плагин. У меня необходимость в плагинах для firefox, и для этого завел профиль браузера, в него установил плагины, а при запуске селениума указывал путь к тому профилю